# How to create schema that have an access as that of dbo and can be accessed by sa user

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, schema, database-schema

I am new to schema, roles and user management part in sql server. Till now I used to work with simple dbo schema but now after reading few articles I am intrested in creating schema for managing my tables in a folder fashion.

At present, I want to create a schema where i want to keep my tables that have same kind of functionality. When I tries to create a schema then I faces a problem while using query, permissions etc.

First of all i want to get used to of using schemas then only I want to explore it. But due to initial stages and work pressure as well i m not able to implement it yet.

What can i do to start using schema with default permissions as that of dbo.
Also let me know about creating roles and assigning roles on these schema. I want all this to be accessible by sa user itself at present.

**What is the concept behind all these things**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically

- The schema has an owner
- Objects in different schemas can access each other with no extra permissions if they have the same owner

Please see my question here: "[SQL Server: How to permission schemas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212044/sql-server-how-to-permission-schemas)" and RBarryYoung's enlightening answer...