# creating multiple users for a c#.net winform application using sql server express

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

i have a single sql database in sql server express.

i have a login MAINLOGIN, for this database.

i want insertion of data in this database through multiple users, U1,U2,U3, each having different  userids & passwords.

These users would be created by MAINLOGIN , manually or via the winform application.

So while creating MAINLOGIN , i would give him permission to further create logins.

For this what should i do?

i cannot create MULTIPLE users, because for one database, only one user can be created under one login.

so should i create multiple logins, L1,L2,L3, then map, U1, U2, U3 to them.

Or, is there a better way to do this? like application roles etc.

i dont want to use windows authentication. because if i know the system password, then i could simply connect sql via the application and insert wrong data.

Comment: You could create a login for a Windows/AD **group**, and then a user for that login; any Windows user who is a member of that **group** now has access to your database tables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can have either accounts based on Windows accounts, or separate, specific SQL accounts. For both variations, you need **one account for each user** that needs to use your database.

The only exception is the ability to create a SQL Server Login for a Windows security **group**, e.g. `MyAppUsers`, and then a user in your database for that login. With this, any Windows account that is member of that security group (in Windows/AD) will also have permissions to see / use your database.

With this approach, you're also moving the administration of who can use your database out of SQL Server, since it really only depends on membership in a Windows security group.

One login, one user - multiple Windows accounts that get permissions with this. Seems like a winner to me!

*Update:*

Create a login for a Windows AD group:

```
CREATE LOGIN [DOMAIN\GroupName] FROM WINDOWS
```

Create a user in your database based on that login:

```
USE (your database)

CREATE USER GroupNameUser 
FOR LOGIN [DOMAIN\GroupName]
```

Connection string for your SQL Server connection:

```
server=(your server);database=(your database);integrated security=SSPI;
```

What else can I tell you?

*Update #2:* the code **not** using the Windows accounts is this:

Create a login for **each** user that needs to use your application

```
CREATE LOGIN (some login name) WITH PASSWORD = 'Top$ecret'
```

Create a user in your database based on that login - again, once for **each user** of your app:

```
USE (your database)

CREATE USER UserName
FOR LOGIN (some login name)
```

Connection string for your SQL Server connection:

```
server=(your server);database=(your database);
  user id=UserName;Password=Top$ecret
```

But again: this requires **one login including a password and one user in each database** which you need to keep track of and possibly do stuff like "reset password" operations etc. from your database app. Lots more in terms of admin overhead!

Comment: @marc_s, if i use windows accounts, then if U-1 leaves his system on , then anybody else can come and start using his system, and open my application and connect to sql database. is there any way to ask password at that time when the unknown person connects to sql server?

Comment: @sqlchild: when using Windows accounts, then you **don't** get to ask for a password; by the fact the user is logged on to Windows is what SQL Server needs - there's no prompting and it cannot be turned on either. If you want that, then you need to use SQL Server accounts (one login + one user for each user of your database)

Comment: @sqlchild: updated my answer - not quite sure what kind of code you're looking for....

Comment: @marc_s : so do you agree with me that i should avoid using windows accounts for my application?

Comment: @sqlchild: Windows accounts are easy to use, no login required, you know exactly who you're dealing with, you can use groups to reduce your management overhead - NO, actually, I think using Integrated Security (Windows accounts) is a good thing and often beneficial!

Comment: @marc_s : i want the code which do not uses windows authentication

Comment: @sqlchild: even if you use explicit SQL Server accounts, you don't get any automatic "disconnect after 10 minutes of inactivity" or anything like that - plus your management overhead is much bigger.

Comment: @marc_s : but the issue which i told, how could it be avoided if i use windows accounts? issue is that , if U-1 has left his machine on,but closed the application, and if someone else comes and open the application and would connect to sql and enter irrelevant data in the sql database. if  the application was closed by U-1 , then will it ask for the password again when it is opened by the unknown user?

Comment: @sqlchild: something like that **cannot** be handled with either SQL accounts nor Windows accounts. This needs to be addressed differently (tell your users to properly log ofF! INstall a password-protected screen saver that kicks in after 30 seconds or something). Neither of the two types of accounts can do anything about that problem....

Comment: @marc_s , if there is a way by which when the unknown user opens the application, then it asks for the windows password again? which was used to switch on the system

Comment: @sqlchild: no - if you use **Windows accounts** for your authentication, there will be **no dialog boxes** and password prompt - NONE.

Comment: @marc_s : but if i use sql accounts then?i mean to say that when the application is opened then it would try to connect to sql server, so i would like to prompt for id and password ? is this possbile?

Comment: @sqlchild: yes, if you use SQL accounts, then you **must** prompt for username/password

Comment: @marc_s, thank you sir, so according to you, the best solution of my posted question is the answer which you have given, that is, i will create L1,L2,L3 logins for my single database, SHOPDB, & then create U1,U2,U3 users mapping to L1,L2,L3?     also, my app. would run on LAN ON 3 systems, so each person will connect to sql server with diff. logins. sql will be installed only on 1 main system.

Answer (score 2):

Maintaining per user connection to SQL is very costly and can lead to poor performace of the application. A better design would be to maintain application roles and allow user permissions via these roles. For connecting SQL - use only one account which is not associated with any user. This account is only used for DB access where are have some audit data in your database to trace who did what.

Comment: sir , you mean to say, that MAINLOGIN , will create application roles for U-1,U-2,U-3 .  and for MAINLOGIN , i will create an application role & then give it to the person who will be using MAINLOGIN.

Comment: for MAINLOGIN to create users U1,U2,U3 , he would need a user also mapped to him, but you are saying that dont create any user for the account which connects to SQL

Comment: sir how do i give permission to a user to add application roles?