# Can stored procedure of one schema access the tables of other schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 .My default schema is dbo. I have tables in schema dbo. But for some  custom development I am planning to create a stored procedure in cdbo schema since it is a custom code. Can I access the tables of dbo schema from sp's of cdbo schema?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2212044/27535

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if the same principal (user) owns both schemas.

This the AUTHORIZATION bit in [CREATE SCHEMA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189462.aspx). If this is dbo for cdbo then no explicit permissions will be needed because of [ownership chaining](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676.aspx)

```
CREATE SCHEMA cdbo AUTHORIZATION dbo;
```